Battery drains rapidly when laptop shuts down, even without fast startup
I have a 2019 Acer Swift SF515-51T-54LK running up-to-date Windows 10.
I replaced the battery a few months ago, but the problem existed before the battery replacement.
I used to set the PC to hibernate when not in use, but found that the battery would drain quickly. I read that this could be due to "modern standby", so I stopped using hibernate and started to shut down the PC. This is annoying, as it requires relaunching all the apps. But most importantly, it does not help with the battery drain.
I read that this could be due to "fast startup", so I disabled that in my control panel.
However, when I shut down my PC, it still goes into a "suspended" state where the battery drains rapidly.
I read that if I pressed the power button for more than 10 seconds, it would properly shut down.
And yet, I've been doing this for a few days, with no success.
Yesterday I shut down my laptop at 6 PM with 59% power.
I pressed the shut-down button for a long time to make sure it was properly off.
This morning I woke up to a PC with 33% power, the battery drained ~1.7% per hour.
The battery report says that the PC was "suspended" at 6 PM yesterday, even though I tried to shut it down completely.
So my questions are :

Why does my PC not seem to properly shut down ever ?
Why does even drain so much battery in the first place, even in hibernate mode ?


Suspended your system is different from hibernation. It’s a different power state. Some devices from 2019 suffered from essentially a bug that caused the battery to drain. There really isn’t a solution to the problem if you had one of those devices since modern standby did not rely on drivers unlike the traditional sleep mode and hibernate mode did historically

Thanks for the pointer @Ramhound, my device is from 2019 indeed !
